# Magento 2: Call phtml file in static block or cms page

Tags: magento2, static-block, phtml

I would like to call a Magento phtml file to a static block I have a custom theme! How to do it, please?
here

```
/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/form.phtml
```

is where the phtml file is located
what should I do to call it ?

```
   /public_html/app/design/frontend/Emthemes/everything/shoppingcenter
```

Comment: what's this file is used for    /public_html/app/design/frontend/Emthemes/everything/shoppingcenter
?

Answer (score 25):

You can use `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` class to call phtml files

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::myfiles/myfile.phtml"}}
```

To call advanced form use `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form` block class.

```
{{block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" name="block_name" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::advanced/form.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 5):

The **`.phtml`** file location will be:

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/Emthemes/everything/shoppingcenter/templates/advanced/form.phtml
```

And calling it on a block like this:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="formblock" template="Vendor_Module::advanced/form.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The .phtml file location will be:
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"}}